# send DateTime through a Ajax.BeginForm #c

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, serialization, ajax.beginform

I'm trying to use Ajax.BeginForm. I want to send a DateTime through a html form.
The problem is in the controller the Datetime is not initialised. I get the default DateTime. Any idea ? Thanks for your help.

My Model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public DateTime myDate { get; set; } 
}
```

My Action in TestController

```
 [HttpPost]
    public void UpdateTest(TestModel tmp)
    {
       tmp.myDate.Date <-- get the wrong date
       ...
       ...
    }
```

My View

```
@model Project.Models.TestModel


@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions()
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    Url = Url.Action("UpdateTest", "Test")
}))
{
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model._id)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.myDate) // example : 18/05/2013 17:00:00


        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: shouldnt you have ActionResult() instead of void

Comment: Yeah you should have ActionResult instead of a void but additionally if you want the myDate property to not be initialized to a default date then make it a nullable type like this:

public DateTime? myDate { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

You must create custom model binder for DateTime and register it on global.asax